# Screen recorder that can record from windows that aren't in the foreground

Tags: windows, screen-recording, video-recording

I have evaluated several different screen recorders for Windows:

- OBS Studio
- Mirillis Action!
- Flashback Express
- Bandicam
- ZDSoft Screen Recorder
- CamStudio
- Apowersoft Screen Recorder Pro

OBS Studio has one very cool feature that all the others lack - the ability to record from a window even if you minimize that window or you move another window in front of it. When you watch an OBS Studio recording of a window that you moved to the background, you will think the window stayed in the foreground the entire time. With all the other programs, they capture only what's on the screen, so if you move another window in front of the window you want to record, then the recording will show that.

Unfortunately, OBS Studio has several issues that make it frequently unusable, so I would like to find another recording software that has the ability to record windows that are not in the foreground.

I did find another program - Applian's Replay Video Capture - that supposedly has that feature, but I was not able to try it out because the program crashes too much.